# htaccess Redirection Causing Internal server error and Repeating the subdomain name many times in the url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have been trying to redirect in .htaccess using the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abcd\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.abcd.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /canada/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This .htaccess code is working fine on a shared hosting server for a different website, but when i copy the same code onto a Virtual Private Server for a different Website, I seem to be getting an Error.

What I have been trying to do is redirect any user who comes to abcd.org to abcd.org/canada but I seem to be getting an Internal Server Error(500) and the url seems to be showing up like this-

```
http://www.abcd.org/canada/canada/canada/canada/canada/canada/canada/canada/canada/canada/........
```

Pls Provide a Solution at the earliest.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abcd\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.abcd.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ canada/ [L,R=301]
```